# Count expressions with 1s and 2s

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Given at most X number of 1s and at most Y number of 2s. How many different evaluation results are possible when they are formed in an expression containing only addition + sign and multiplication * sign are allowed?

Note that, multiplication takes precedence over addition.

For example, if A=2 and B=2, then we have the following expressions:

```
1, 1*1 = 1
2, 1*2, 1*1*2, 1+1 = 2
1+2, 1+1*2 = 3
2+2, 2*2, 1+1+2, 1*2*2, 1*1*2*2, 1*2+1*2, 1*1*2+2, 1*2+2 = 4
1+2+2, 1+1*2+2 = 5
1+1+2+2 = 6
```

So there are 6 unique results that can be formed if A = 2 and B = 2.
So here answer would be 6.

---

#### Source

This question is from  [March 2014 Hacker Rank contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/mar14/challenges/ones-and-twos) which has ended by now.

Comment: Where does this question come from, please?

Comment: i can't even *begin* to think how this can be done.

Comment: 'Note that, multiplication takes precedence over addition.' Does this mean that expressions like $(1+2) \cdot (1+2+2)$ are not allowed? (If this is the case, the largest number that can be formed is $2^B+A$, and I think that all numbers below it can be formed, using some characteristics of powers of two)

Comment: If you're allowed $m$ $1$'s and $n$ $2$'s, the *largest* number you can form is $2^n+m$, so perhaps things can be approached by asking how many (if any) smaller numbers can *not* be expressed by adding and/or multiplying a limited number of $1$'s and $2$'s.

Comment: @user45878, I see we're thinking along the same lines!  I'm a little less certain you can always get all smaller numbers, though.  For one thing, you certainly need at least one $1$:  If $A$ (or $m$) is $0$, you can only get even numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/mar14/challenges/ones-and-twos

Answer (score 4):

These are some thoughts toward a solution.

As user45878 and I noted in comments, the largest number you can get in the prescribed fashion using at most $m$ $1$'s and $n$ $2$'s is $2^n+m$.  Moreover, you can clearly get all numbers from $2^n$ to $2^n+m$.  So the problem boils down to asking how many numbers *less than* $2^n$ can you form?

Since $1\times1=1$ and $1\times2=2$, we may as well limit ourselves to considering expressions of the form

$$2\circ2\circ\cdots\circ2+1+1+\cdots+1$$

where the expression contains up to $n$ $2$'s and $m$ $1$'s, and each "$\circ$" is either a "$+$" or a "$\times$."  There are additional simplifications as well.  The $2\circ2\circ\cdots\circ2$ part can be rewritten as

$$2^a+2^b+\cdots+2^z$$

with $a\gt b\gt\cdots\gt z\gt0$ and $a+b+\cdots+z\le n$.  The role of the $1$'s is to try to fill in the gaps between numbers that can be written with a limited number of powers of $2$.

An example might help.  Let's consider $n=4$.  The distinct possibilities for $2\circ\cdots\circ2$ are $2$, $2^2$, $2^2+2$, $2^3$, $2^3+2$, and $2^4$, that is,

$$2,4,6,8,10,16$$

We see that the numbers $1,3,5,7,9,11,12,13,14$, and $15$ are missing.  If $m=1$, we pick up $1,3,5,7,9$, and $11$.  With each additional $1$, we pick up one more number until we reach $m=5$.  One might express this as follows:

$$M_4(0)=10,\quad M_4(1)=4,\quad M_4(2)=3,\quad M_4(3)=2,\quad M_4(4)=1,\quad M_4(5)=0$$

where $M_n(m)$ denotes the numbers up to $2^n$ (or, if you like, $2^n+m$) that are "missing" from the prescribed expressions with at most $m$ $1$'s and $n$ $2$'s.  One can obviously obtain the number of "present" numbers as

$$P(m,n)=2^n+m-M_n(m)$$

If I have any additional (or multiplicative) thoughts, I'll post them.

Comment: is there any generalized way of finding unique possibilities for n in 2∘⋯∘2 like you did for 4